# RxJava 2: always unsubscribe on the .subscribeOn(..) scheduler?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have an `Observable<String>` that performs some work. After its done, it closes its connections (via `.setDisposable(Disposables.fromAction(logic*);`. Trouble is, I need this close action to be performed on the same scheduler as the actual workload.

Is it possible? How?

*I dont want to force the Observable to perform on a given scheduler, e.g.* `myObservable.subscribeOn(x).unsubscribeOn(x);`;

Comment: Did you try observerOn operaor before that setDisposable?

Comment: @paul I think you misunderstood my question. Im only interested in coupling the scheduler used between unsubscribeOn and subscribeOn.

Answer (score 4):

You need a single threaded scheduler for that to work and you can get one via `Schedulers.from(Executor)` or new `SingleScheduler` (warning: internal).

The problem with `unsubscribeOn` is that it runs only if the downstream actually disposes/cancels the stream (unlike 1.x where this happens almost all the time).

A better way is to use `using` with the aforementioned custom scheduler and manually schedule the cleanup:

```
Observable<T> createObservable(Scheduler scheduler) {
    return Observable.create(s -> {
        Resource res = ...

        s.setCancellable(() -> 
            scheduler.scheduleDirect(() ->
                res.close() // may need try-catch here
            )
        );

        s.onNext(...);
        s.onComplete();
    }).subscribeOn(scheduler);
}

Scheduler scheduler = new SingleScheduler();

createObservable(scheduler)
.map(...)
.filter(...)
.subscribe(...);
```

But note that unless the `create` logic gives up the scheduler (by terminating or going async), the cancellation logic may not ever execute due to same-pool livelock.

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont have access to the scheduler -- its only available in the "parent" observable: e.g. Observable.combineLatest(obs1,obs2).subscribeOn(...) where obs1 or obs2 would be the observable in your answer.

Comment: Then you have to redesign your code including the parent.

Comment: @akarnokd I am having the same-pool livelock you mentioned: my code is blocked on a sync `input.readLine()` therefore I can't release the thread so that I can use it to call the cancellable. Any thoughts?

Comment: Closing an `InputStream` asynchronously will unblock a `read()`, but then you can't reuse the same thread. If it is really important you close the input on the same thread it has been opened, the remaining option is to call readLine on yet another thread/`Scheduler`.