# RxJava2 create Flowable from listener and remove listener at the end

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

My use case is related to using RxJava2 with Firebase Database.

I have a [DatabaseReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference) and I can register value listeners to it.
I can transform it into a flowable like this:

```
disposable = Flowable.create<DataSnapshot>({ s ->
            dbRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {...}

                override fun onDataChange(value: DataSnapshot) {
                    s.onNext(value)
                }
            })
        }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
        .subscribe(...)
```

I would like to be able to remove the listener when the disposable is disposed.
Any idea how I can do that?

I saw that in rxjava 1 there was [this possibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26695125/how-to-get-notified-of-a-observers-unsubscribe-action-in-a-custom-observable-in) maybe, but it's not available in rxjava2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With RxJava2 you need to use the [setCancellable()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/FlowableEmitter.html#setCancellable(io.reactivex.functions.Cancellable)) method, and put your listener removal code there.
This is much like [Emitter.setCancellation()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Emitter.html#setCancellation(rx.functions.Cancellable)) from RxJava1, when creating Observable with [Observable.fromEmitter()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#fromEmitter(rx.functions.Action1,%20rx.Emitter.BackpressureMode)).

Take also this note by [akarnokd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61158/akarnokd) regarding cancellation:
"But note that unless the create logic gives up the scheduler (by terminating or going async), the cancellation logic may not ever execute due to same-pool livelock."
([RxJava 2: always unsubscribe on the .subscribeOn(..) scheduler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40508955/rxjava-2-always-unsubscribe-on-the-subscribeon-scheduler))